# How to work out coordinates while using Robot Framework with Selenium2Library?

Tags: selenium-webdriver, robotframework

I need to use "Click Element at Coordinates" keyword in my test cases, I understand x and y offsets are in respect to the center of the chosen element, but how do I work out the exact coordinates of an element?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved my problem by trial and error,

1. try a random coordinates, if it shows up on map, where is it?
2. keep x axis the same, change y axis
3. keep y axis the same, change x axis

By doing this, I managed to get a rough idea.

Answer (score 1):

You can extend Robot Framework library to include AutoItLibrary and use Mouse Get Pos X and Mouse Get Pos Y to get the initial coordinates and then follow it up with click element at Click Element At Coordinates.